# Change appearance of menu item depending on page address

Tags: html, css

I wish to change the appearance (background colour) of an item of a navigation menu item depending on the current page.

Here is the HTML code I have for my navigation menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Recruitment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training & Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Outsourcing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS code I have for my navigation menu:

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    border-radius: 6px;   
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom:1;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
/*  border-right: 1px solid #222;
*/  
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #fafafa;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
    background: #444;   
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);  
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);      
}

#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {   
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #f80033;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f80033, #955d61);
}

#menu li:hover {
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: #f80033;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f80033, #955d61);
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #444;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0; 
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #3b3b3b;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #f80033; 
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #ba4d5c; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

Comment: its working perfect. whats the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/TNUG2/

Comment: You want to highlight the menu item linking to the current page? If so this is impossible without either server, or client, side scripting; CSS has (as yet) no concept of the page's location.

Comment: @Era i want active menu if i move to other page

Comment: and you want to achieve this with css only ? as David said its not possible only with CSS. you need to include jquery for this.

Comment: @Era may i know how to do that help me

Comment: @Era: no, jQuery's not necessary; [tag:php], [tag:ruby], [tag:asp.net] and plain [tag:javascript] (among many others) can achieve this.

Comment: @DavidThomas : I am talking about quick and easiest way.

Comment: I'm not convinced that jQuery's significantly easier or quicker than the alternatives but yes, it's an option.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a selector to `#menu li:hover` making it `#menu li:hover, #menu li.active` and then, simply add the class `active` to teh `<li>` you want to highlight when the page is loaded.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/mofeqase/1/edit?html,css,output

In order to make the selection "automatically", you will need some script to add the `active` class to the correct `li`... normally, and to make it simple I go with:

```
var pageUrl = window.location.href;
$("#menu a[href='" + pageUrl + "']").parent().addClass("active");
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the attribute might contain only a relative URL, causing this approach to fail, it'd probably be best to select the relevant elements and then filter using the `element.href` property (for the full URL) to compare that against `window.location.href`. Mind you, both our approaches would fail given that the `href` of *every* link is, in the posted code, simply `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:active` selector to pick out the currently active menu item.

<strike>http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp</strike>

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/

Comment: maybe you didn't understand... W3Schools have wrong information across all website! DO NOT use them! period.

Comment: I removed the link in favor of a CSS-Tricks page. Not sure what else you want from me :P Also, W3Schools isn't the greatest learning tool, but as a quick-reference, I've found the answers I've been looking for more times than I can count from there. It's not all bad.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding there are two ways of doing this :

1. Write server side code to add a class like `active` when the tab path is same as page path (You can also compare the controller action).
2. You can also do this with javascript by using `window.location` and comparing it with tab link.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to assign a CSS class on the click even of the item, in which case you'll need to use javascript (see jQuery below), alternatively you'll need to identify the current page on page load and assign a class to the relevant list item at that time (implementation not shown, see answer from [balexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28004/balexandre)).

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/4y6ET/1/)

jQuery

```
$('#menu > li').on('click', function(){
    $('#menu > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');   
});
```

Additional CSS

```
#menu li.active {
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color: #f80033;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#f80033, #955d61);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class for the link which you want to be shown active

and add css for that class.

For example:

```
a.active{background-color:#f80033;color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only CSS cant perform this action and you need to add jquery : **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TNUG2/2/)**

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){
    $('#menu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: When the new page loads the styling applied by `.active` Will be lost (assuming it's not a single-page site).